# SocketIO Timeout until forever

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to make all clients try to reconnect forever ?

I have a server computer that shuts-down during the night. But also have clients that never shut-down, so when the server is down, all clients fail to connect. I need them to keep trying forever, until the server goes up again, and that could be hours.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post some code on how you are doing the connection now.

Comment: I dont do anything special in Server all do is: 
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

and in Client 
var socket = io();

Comment: We need to see your client code that establishes the connection.  And, we need to know why you think the clients don't keep trying to re-establish the connection forever since that appears to be the default settings for a socket.io connection.